# Trouble calling data from an other file

Tags: json, ruby

I know it's something pretty straight forward, but I'm having trouble getting the value I want from a JSon data file.

I have two file, one is called test.rb and look like this :

```
require_relative 'suppliers_data' 

class SelectSupplier
  def self.suppliers
    suppliers.sort_by { |e| e[:advitam_grade].to_i }.reverse
  end
end
```

and the other called suppliers_data looks like this :

```
suppliers = [
{ name: "FunePlus",
  advitam_grade: 3,
  works: [
    { type: "embalming", price: 350 },
    {type: "transport_before_casketing", price: 450} ]},
{ name: "FuneTop",
  works: [
    { type: "graving", price: 10} ]},
{ name: "FuneTruc",
  advitam_grade: 5,
  works: [
    { type: "embalming", price: 750} ]},
{ name: "FuneCorp",
  advitam_grade: 2,
  works: [
    { type: "digging", price: 350} ]}
```

]

As you might imagine, my def `self.suppliers`doesn't work and I have this error `suppliers': stack level too deep`

I've tried to look around what did I do wrong but didn't find something really interesting.

does any of you have a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for this error is an unbounded recursion

```
def self.suppliers
    suppliers. # calls itself recursively
      sort_by { |e| e[:advitam_grade].to_i }.reverse

end
```

Comment: but with a comment :)
try to rename self.supplies to self.process_suppliers and see what happens

Comment: Yeah, I get what you wrote a bit late :) but now, I have an undefined local or method suppliers.

Comment: quick fix would be to update suppliers_data and rename variable
suppliers = [...]
into 
SUPPLIERS = [..]

and then rewrite the method to look like

def self.suppliers
    SUPPLIERS.sort_by { |e| e[:advitam_grade].to_i }.reverse
  end

Comment: Thanks for that ! I did think about that before asking the question and I had this error 'undefined local variable or method `suppliers' for main:Object'

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it completely wrong (ruby does not natively support storing/loading unserialized objects from/to disk,)  but it’s ruby and everything is doable:

```
class SelectSupplier
  def self.suppliers
    instance_eval '@' << File.read('suppliers_data')
    @suppliers.sort_by { |e| e[:advitam_grade].to_i }.reverse
  end
end
```

The proper solution for this task would be to serialize your data to either JSON or YAML, load the file and deserialize data back.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but I don't really understand what the ìnstance_eval and the @ are for ..

Comment: In any case the answer provided by @mibon below is better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the "stack level too deep" exception is that `SelectSupplier::suppliers` calls itself instead of the variable. This is because the variable is out of scope. You can solve this in one of 2 ways.

1. Using a constant definition.

   To make a variable into a constant you have to upcase the name. Furthermore, constants are normally constant like the name suggest. To prevent changes you would normally freeze the values. Since your data structure is relatively complex for a constant the freezing process is pretty complicated. Normally constants are used for simple things like the days of week, or allowed options. For this reason I wouldn't recommend using a constant.

   ```
   SUPPLIERS = [
     {
       name: 'FunePlus',
       advitam_grade: 3,
       works: [
         {type: 'embalming', price: 350},
         {type: 'transport_before_casketing', price: 450},
       ],
     }, # {
       # ...
     # }
   ].freeze.each do |supplier|
     supplier.freeze.each_value(&:freeze)
     supplier[:works].each(&:freeze).each { |work| work.each_value(&:freeze) }
   end
   ```

   Then use `SUPPLIERS` instead of `suppliers` in your method.
2. Using a global variable.

   Global variables should be avoided, but it is an option nonetheless. To make a global variable you have to prefix your variable with a `$`.

   ```
   $supliers = [
     # ...
   ]
   ```

   Then use `$suppliers` instead of `suppliers` in your method.

Both above solutions aren't great, this is due to your design. If you're planning to hold those values in memory you might as well use a class. This way you can add some custom methods for the instances. The following might give you an idea how such a class can look:

```
class Supplier
  @suppliers = [
    # ...
  ]

  class << self
    attr_reader :suppliers

    # initialize an instance with an id
    def find(id)
      supplier = suppliers[id]

      return unless supplier

      new(id: id, **suppliers)
    end

    # initialize an instance with an attribute
    def find_by(attributes)
      supplier = suppliers.find do |supplier|
        attributes.all? { |attr, val| supplier[attr] == val }
      end

      return unless supplier

      new(id: suppliers.index(supplier), **supplier)
    end
  end

  # create getters for attributes
  attr_reader :id, :name, :advitam_grade, :works

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @id = attributes.delete(:id)
    attributes.each { |attr, value| public_send("#{attr}=", value) }
    @initialized = true
  end

  # create setters that update the source hash if the instance is
  # initialized
  %i[name advitam_grade works].each do |symbol|
    define_method("#{symbol}=") do |value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{symbol}", value)
      # you can't use return in a block, so instead use break
      break unless @initialized
      update(symbol)
    end
  end

  # return the source hash
  def source
    klass[id]
  end

  private

  # update the source hash with the instance attribute value
  def update(attr)
    klass[id][attr] = public_send(attr)
  end

  def klass
    self.class
  end

end
```